# Why doesn't output caching middleware recognize the root controller URL in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET application. The Index method that loads the page performs queries on a database. These queries are expensive and that datasets change infrequently, so this is a perfect use case for caching.

I added the output caching middleware to my `Program.cs` file.

I want to cache the server-side output, so I added flags to my Index functions:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 43200, NoStore = false)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    some code...
}
```

When I access the page using: `https://web.app.com/Controller/Index` the page caches as expected. However, when I use: `https://web.app.com/Controller/` (which routes to the same endpoint) the page fails to cache, even after refreshing.

I understand that each unique URL should be cached by the server. Is there any reason why the root URL is being ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my app setup in `Program.cs` from:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

to:

```
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
```

For some reason, this fixed the problem--the root URL for the controller is now being cached.

Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) states that `MapDefaultControllerRoute()` is a convenience method that is equivalent to the first code snippet.

If anyone knows why this would make a difference, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason is '/' character in the end of "https://web.app.com/Controller/". Try to get rid of it or use redirection:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("^(.*[^/])$", "$1/");
app.UseRewriter(options);
```